# How to detect if a whole point cloud is under or on top of a given line?

Tags: precision, numerical-methods

This question is related to [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513867/relative-localisation-of-3d-planar-lines-and-points?noredirect=1#comment5200516_2513867).

**tl;dr**: in a given plane lies a cloud of point. I'm moving a line in this plane and I want to know if every points of my point cloud is on the *same side of the line*.

This is how I do it (pseudo code):

```
bool same_side(PointCloud pc, Point a, Point b, Plane plane):
   L := Vector(a,b)  // the line
   n := L.cross_product(plane.normal)
   bottom, top, zero := 0
   for each p in pc:
      current_result := Vector(a, p).dot_product(n)
      if(current_result < -EPSILLON)
         bottom++
      else if(current_result >= -EPSILLON && current_result <= EPSILLON)
         zero++
      else
         top++

   return top == 0 OR bottom == 0
```

Where `EPSILLON` positive value such as `0.000000001`.
You can see that I'm not using `zero` in this code, just as an illustration.

**The problem** is that when the line gets closer to the point cloud, some lines aren't detected to be crossing the point cloud.

I think this as to do with accuracy and whether or not a point is triggering a `top` or `bottom` increment.
I already tried with different values of `EPSILLON` from 0 to 0.01 without any satisfying results.

**My question** is how to handle this ?

Comment: Normalizing vector `n` may help.

Comment: Thanks for answering @SourabhBhat, I've normalized vectors `n` and `Vector(a, p)` but nothing changed.

Comment: Are the points also in the plane ?? If not, "on the same side of the line" is meaningless.